# How to execute programs/commands in .net core webapp (like Django's manage.py)

Tags: .net, django

I have been a Django developer for over 5 years now and am looking for creating new projects in .NET.

I have created a few hobby projects in .NET and the experience was quite good. But I have a question, to which I haven't found the answer.

To give an example: Django has built in management commands and options to write your own. One of the options is `createsuperuser`. For example, when you setup your django project, you can call `python manage.py createsuperuser` and it will create a superuser for you. You can create custom commands, which can be run locally and in production servers.

How can I do this in `.net` if I have a webapp? How can I run commands/programs locally or on production server/kubernetes pod? Is this even possible? I know you can create multiple projects inside the solution beside webapp project.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing build-in AFAIK. The closest option would be to just create a console app and implement any required logic there and run it (for example `dotnet mymanagementapp.dll someargument`).

Additionally you can package and distribute it as a [global tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools-how-to-create). There are several [existing ones](https://www.nuget.org/packages?packageType=dotnettool&sortBy=relevance), for example the one for [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet) (or to profile and diagnose .NET apps - [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/tools-overview)). But I don't know global tools for ASP.NET Core (or [identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)) related management.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I can have a webapp project and a console app project(s), which can then be packaged together in docker image. Then in docker container I can just run `dotnet mymanagementapp.dll`?

Comment: @Razmooo for example yes. But personally I would just expose the needed operations as APIs of the web project and hide them behind auth.

Answer (score 0):

Haha.  I am a .Net developer now dabbling in Python.
If I understand your question correctly, you want to run ad hoc commands on your webserver.  I don't think there is the direct equivalent of manage.py.

You can run IIS with some command line arguments as here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line.
This would  be roughly the equivalent of manage.py runserver.
You can publish to your dev m/c IIS and run it with args to debug.

I suppose a slightly better answer would be to use a proper mvc pattern (not necessarily MS MVC) and call the back-end API via something like Swagger before you have built the UI.

Otherwise, I sometimes build a test harness.  This can be a simple console app in the same solution, where you instantiate classes and call their methods to do what you want.